# how to validate the form on the particular button click?

Tags: jquery

I have four buttons on my page

```
<button id="opener"  >Submit Timecard</button>
<button id="cancel" class="cancel">Cancel</button>
<input type="button" onclick="AddPO();" class="cancel"  id="btnAddPO" name="btnAddPO" value="Add More Part Details"/>
<input type="button" name="btnAddMoreReciepts" id="btnAddMoreReciepts" value="Add More Reciepts" onclick="AddReciepts();" class="cancel"  />
```

When the Submit Timecard is clicked the form should validate.
for the rest of the buttons it should not so I added the class cancel.
But if I Click btnAddPo or btnAddMoreReciepts first and click the SubmitTimecard  the form is not getting validated.

Can anyone tell me a good solution for this

Thanks,
Sravanthi

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have a javascript function for validate().  You can bind that function to the click handler for just the button you need.

```
$('selector for submit timecard').click(function(){validate();});
```

This is a very general solution, and you can also include the validation function on the form submit action.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have function available to validate form, you can simply write the code like below....

Function to validate..

```
function validate(){
    // do the required validation here
}
```

usage ..

```
<button id="opener"  onClick="validate();" >Submit Timecard</button>
```

this will trigger the validate function whenever you click this button and doesn't change even if you have other buttons ...

Hope this helps ..